# Parse/search trough cascaded arrays in JSON

Tags: json, python-3.x, for-loop

I need to read trough following json response below

I'm searching for the ID of a special folder.
I know the level of deep, where I will expect to find the folder, as I know the whole path.
I need to get the ID of the folder back.

What I know is the whole path of the folder I'm looking for, so for example /Core/UI/Folder1/Subfolder2
So I need the ID of subfolder2.

I have tried several loops but failed due to the search in the deep.
Sure I can code some manual level of deep stuff but that doesn't sounds to be the right way I would think.

Example JSON

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "rank": 1,
            "name": "Core",
            "id": 390,
            "testCount": 0,
            "totalTestCount": 0,
            "testRepositoryPath": "",
            "folders": [
                {
                    "rank": 1,
                    "name": "UI",
                    "id": 391,
                    "testCount": 0,
                    "totalTestCount": 0,
                    "testRepositoryPath": "/Core",
                    "folders": [
                        {
                            "rank": 1,
                            "name": "Folder1",
                            "id": 392,
                            "testCount": 0,
                            "totalTestCount": 0,
                            "testRepositoryPath": "/Core/UI",
                            "folders": [
                                {
                                    "rank": 1,
                                    "name": "Subfolder2",
                                    "id": 393,
                                    "testCount": 0,
                                    "totalTestCount": 0,
                                    "testRepositoryPath": "/Core/UI/Folder1",
                                    "folders": []
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "allTestsCount": 791,
    "allOrphanTestsCount": 791
}
```

Comment: is it based on "name" or "testRepositoryPath"?

Comment: the combination of name and testRepositoryPath would match the whole path

Comment: Your desired path doesn't match your JSON. Please fix your question and make sure you sepcify EXACTLY what you want from what you have.  Tell us the inputs and desired outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, if I understand you correctly, this should work, please let me know:

```py
data = {
    "folders": [
        {
            "rank": 1,
            "name": "Core",
            "id": 390,
            "testCount": 0,
            "totalTestCount": 0,
            "testRepositoryPath": "",
            "folders": [
                {
                    "rank": 1,
                    "name": "UI",
                    "id": 391,
                    "testCount": 0,
                    "totalTestCount": 0,
                    "testRepositoryPath": "/Core",
                    "folders": [
                        {
                            "rank": 1,
                            "name": "Folder1",
                            "id": 392,
                            "testCount": 0,
                            "totalTestCount": 0,
                            "testRepositoryPath": "/Core/UI",
                            "folders": [
                                {
                                    "rank": 1,
                                    "name": "Subfolder2",
                                    "id": 393,
                                    "testCount": 0,
                                    "totalTestCount": 0,
                                    "testRepositoryPath": "/Core/UI/Folder1",
                                    "folders": []
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "allTestsCount": 791,
    "allOrphanTestsCount": 791
}


def extract_inner_id(d, path):
    try:
        current_path = d['testRepositoryPath'] + '/' + d['name']
        if current_path == path:
            return d['id']
    except KeyError:
        pass
    for sub_d in d['folders']:
        inner_id = extract_inner_id(sub_d, path)
        if inner_id is not None:
            return inner_id
    return None


print(extract_inner_id(data, "/Core/UI/Folder1/Subfolder2"))
```

notice we call `extract_inner_id` from within itself for every sub-folder, that's how we search no matter how deep.

Comment: @JörgLang maybe I didn't understand correctly. is this condition right? `if sub_d['testRepositoryPath'] + '/' + sub_d['name'] == path:` ?

Comment: I have updated the JSON in the original post.... I would say yes that sub_d['testRepositoryPath'] + '/' + sub_d['name'] == path is correct if Im not wrong

Comment: @JörgLang OK, found it! it had to do with the fact the the top-level data didn't have 'name' and 'testRepositoryPath'. please try now :)